# How do I include a dependency package in a snap?

Tags: python3, snap

I was playing around, trying to wrap the orca package in a snap:

```
name: orca
version: 1
summary: orca
description: screen reader
confinement: strict

apps:
  orca:
    command: usr/bin/orca

parts:
  orca:
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages:
      - gnome-orca
```

That "snaps" and installs just fine but when I run `orca` python complains that it can't import pyatspi.

/snap/orca/100001/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyatspi/ is present so I'm wondering if there is some kind of permissions problem.

Later: just running the python interpreter in the snap and importing the pyatspi module gives an error:

```
>>> import pyatspi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/orca/100001/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyatspi/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Atspi
  File "/snap/orca/100001/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 127, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Atspi, introspection typelib not found
```

The Atspi typelib does appear to be present, albeit in a different location to most others:

```
...
/snap/orca/100001/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Atspi-2.0.typelib
/snap/orca/100001/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/DBus-1.0.typelib
...
```

Comment: This is on Xubuntu 16.04 and orca is not installed on the host system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the packages whose contents you want bundled in your snap under `stage-packages` too. For https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/2048/snapcraft.yaml this is for example:

```
stage-packages:
  - qml-module-qtquick2
  - qmlscene
```